# Full table background color in swing

Tags: java, swing, background

I'm building my Java application interface using a lot of Photoshop.
But after implementing a table it doesn't look pretty cool as you can see:

[image: Interface]

I would like to make the table as transparent as possible, so only letters are shown. I have setted all the colors to black.
Any solution?

Comment: Check the background of all the parent components.  The table is added to some panel that may be set to default grey.

Comment: @MichaelMcKay Neither `JTable` or `JScrollPane` or transparent by default

Comment: @MadProgrammer Agree. But they are not black by default either.  I'd loop up through the parents to find the culprit. Without the code, its not clear what is containing what.

Answer (score 2):

[`JTable#setFillsViewportHeight`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setFillsViewportHeight-boolean-) would be the starting point.

Make sure that the background color of the `JTable` has been set accordingly